# Adding icon to <li> menu

Tags: php, html-lists

> i am working on a school project and I am stuck at a point where i
>   want to put an image ( >><< ) inbetween `<li>`-tags. Because it's a
>   navigation in wordpress it's done in php.
>
> Here is what i have:
>
> [img http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/253/screenshot20120529at305.png](http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/253/screenshot20120529at305.png)
>
> Here is what i want (look at the blue thingies in between the menu
>   items):
>
> [img http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/253/screenshot20120529at305.png](http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/253/screenshot20120529at305.png)
>
> I think this is the php where i need to put my image/menuitem.png..
>   but where? Help would very much be appreciated
>
> ```
> function inkthemes_nav() {
>     if (function_exists('wp_nav_menu'))
>         wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'custom_menu', 'container_id' => 'menu', 'menu_class' => 'ddsmoothmenu',
> ```
>
> 'fallback_cb' => 'inkthemes_nav_fallback'));
>           else
>               inkthemes_nav_fallback();
>       }
>
> ```
> function inkthemes_nav_fallback() {
>     ?>
>     <div id="menu">
>         <ul class="ddsmoothmenu">
>             <?php
>             wp_list_pages('title_li=&show_home=1&sort_column=menu_order');
>             ?>
>         </ul>
>     </div>
>     <?php
> }
>
> function inkthemes_home_nav_menu_items($items) {
>     if (is_home()) {
>     //home
>         $homelink = '<li class="current_page_item">' . '<a href="' . home_url('/') . '">' . __('Home', 'themia') . '</a></li>';
>     } else {
>      //niet home
>         $homelink = '<li>' . '<a href="' . home_url('/') . '">' . __('Home', 'themia') . '</a></li>/>';
>
>     }
>     $items = $homelink . $items;
>     return $items;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a CSS-Only solution:

```
.ddsmoothmenu li {
  background: url('image/menuitem.png') no-repeat left center;
  padding-left:30px /* you have to adjust this manually */
}
.ddsmoothmenu li:first-child{
  background:none;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

Comment: it is better to use :first-child than :last-child, because the latter doesnt work in ie7 and ie8

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add an image tag at both locations that say HERE, however that would also put an image behind the last item.

```
$homelink = '<li class="current_page_item">' . '<a href="' . home_url('/') . '">' . __('Home', 'themia') . '</a></li> HERE';
    } else {
     //niet home
 $homelink = '<li>' . '<a href="' . home_url('/') . '">' . __('Home', 'themia') . '</a></li>/> HERE';
```

Better would be to add it using css, something like:

```
#menu li {
 padding-right: 30px;
 background: url('path/to/image') no-repeat right center;
}

#menu li:last-child {
 background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the css property [`list-style-image`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp). You may prevent this on the first one with the css class `:first-child`

Here as an example:

```
.ddsmoothmenu li {
    list-style-image: url('image/menuitem.png');
}
.ddsmoothmenu li:first-child{
    list-style-image:none;
}
```

Comment: `list-style-image` doesn't [play nice with IE](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/list-style-image#compatibilitysection).

Comment: Does this matter of newer versions than 7?