# CSS: icon for each <li> that floats in the middle of the line

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists

At the get-go, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXWPE/).

I want a `<ul>` in which each `<li>` has a `<p>` and then an icon floating on the rhs. The paragraph may take 1-4 lines, and I want the icon to sit nicely in the middle of the line no matter what. The double wrapping `<p>` is necessary, trust me :)

The width of the `<p>` has to be 100% less whatever space is necessary for the icon. Basically, I want the icon to sit halfway up the space left by the right-margin of the `<p>`.

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799933/adding-icon-to-li-menu) uses `background-image`, but that's no good for me because the image has to serve as a draggable handle for mobile devices. (I'm using [this approach](http://miguelrodelas.com/web/2011/11/09/make-jquery-ui-sortable-dragdrop-work-on-ipad-safari/) to modify a jQuery sortable desktop site for touch screen.)

The fiddle uses a placeholder `<img>` because of the demands of jsfiddle, but I'll actually use an `<a>` with an image off a sprite.

I want to avoid having a negative top margin, because the margin will move into the preceding line and could mess up the dragging (i.e., you could inadvertently drag the wrong line).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6295861/993915) by [bfrohs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526741/bfrohs),

[**DEMO** here](http://jsbin.com/ahomup/10/)

**HTML**

```
  <ul>
    <li class="absoluteCenterWrapper">
        <p class="text">This is some text that flows over multiple lines and I want it to have the icon on the rhs that stays in the middle of the line no matter how many lines of text (and I'd really like not to use a negative top margin on the image).</p>
        <img class="icon" src="http://placekitten.com/g/20/20">
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.text {
    margin-right:35px;
}

.absoluteCenterWrapper {
    position:relative;
}

.icon {
     margin:auto;
     position:absolute; 
     max-height:100%;
     max-width:100%;
     top:0;
     bottom:0;
     right:0;
}
```

Comment: This, my friend, is a thing of beauty :)  Great job; thanks a heap. BTW, the `.absoluteCenter` CSS at the end is redundant. I also think that the `.absoluteCenterWrapper` does not need to be floating right for it to work, although I'm not sure here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change the position of the li element to be absolute and that of the img also absolute. Consider adding this code instead of using your css.

```
.icon{
margin:40% 5%;
float:right;position:absolute;
}
```

​
See this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/NXWPE/47/

Comment: Thanks, Sumit, although I've gone with Pranav's solution. You also need to make the line `position:relative` else the icon moves up and down the whole page :)